# Backup got stuck (?) and now I can't reach the back end

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, admin-panel, backup

I'm  very new to Magento so sincere apologies if this question has already been asked.

Around 1100 on Friday, May 27 I started a database and media backup. After I started it, there was a 'please wait' spinning wheel for a while, which later disappeared. After that, the website went down for maintenance, which I expected. However, I am now unable to access the backend either. It is now 1800 on 29 May. Both sides now show the following:

'Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.'

Help. I assume that the backup has been too large and has overwhelmed the server? I arrived to the website with it having not been backed up in years (I know this is a major problem, which is why I set the backup going asap).

How can I stop the backup, which I assume is still running, get back into the backend and get the site up again?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ftp into your server and delete `maintenance. flag` file in your magento installation directory. It is completely safe.

This happens often. Magento does not have the rights to delete the file when the process is done.